# Android - How to Inject custom audio during call

Tags: java, android

I wonder if there is a way to play audio (like mp3 files) in the background of a phone call on non-rooted android devices.

Answer (score 0):

no this is not possible since you can not access the telephony audio stream in any way

Comment: And what about Skype and Viber calls ?

Comment: all internet telephony apps use the standard audio stream of the device so this should be possible. But what you need is to modify the sources of that providers in order to access those streams. Maybe this can help: 
https://github.com/jenkinsci/skype-im-plugin

Comment: I don't quite understand the part about modifying the sources of the providers, especially since Skype and Viber aren't open source